# Unable to install software and script kept on running (DSC)

Tags: powershell, powershell-dsc

I have one server and we want software installation by DSC. I am trying it locally first then I will publish runbook on Azure. WhenI run the script everything runs fine and it stuck on initial module loading.

```
Configuration TableauReader {
Node localhost {​
    Package Tableau {​
        Name = "Tableau Reader 2019.2 (20192.19.0818.2120)"​
        Path = "C:\SOFT\tableau-setup-rdr-tableau-2019-2.19.0818.2120-x64.msi"​
        Arguments = 'INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Tableau Desktop" /S /V/qn'​
        Ensure    = "Present"​
        ProductID = 'DC4F8081-7A87-4537-8DE7-XXXXXXXXXXXX29FAF3'​
        ReturnCode = 0​
        }​
    }​
}​
```

TableauReader

Comment: Normally you need an elevated prompt to access remote powershell to localhost.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit weird, if I paste your code into VSCode I get errors. 
If I write out the same stuff then No errors.

It might be worth writing it out again long hand. Maybe something went crazy with the encoding?
Also I added backticks to the Arguments file path. Arguments = "`"c:\blahblah`" /i" because I think Powershell will parse them otherwise.

When you say the module loading is stuck what do you mean?

[Error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/065WJ.png)